# swap two number without using a temporary variable

Tags: c++, c

I found this common solution :-

```
int a=10, b=20;    
a=a+b;
b=a-b;
a=a-b;
```

But what if a=2147483647     the largest value of an integer then probably a=a+b will not be feasible.

Comment: Then it won't work. Now think bitwise ops.

Comment: Take both of variable as `unsigned lon long int`, help you to some extent :)

Comment: I know there is a very convoluted way to do this with bits. Unfortunately, I've been unable to find that recently. If you are worried about overflow, I'd use a large integer to store the value. Otherwise, there isn't much you can do with this approach.

Comment: You do realize that the extra variable is going to be a register in the machine, and that using that extra variable will most probably be faster to execute and simpler to read, right?

Comment: As far as I remember our professor who taught this to us said that on adding 1 to the largest +ve integer the answer will come to the smallest -ve integer. And on subtracting 1 from the smallest -ve integer the answer will come to the largest +ve integer. That is how he explained the concept of overflow. So that must not cause a problem here.

Comment: For C++: `using std::swap; swap(a, b);`. No extra variable in sight, *and* works for types other than `int`, and gets best performance when somebody has specialized `swap` for their particular type.

Comment: @iluvthee07 - overflow and underflow of signed types have undefined behavior; the results that you describe are common, but not required.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution is:

```
a ^= b;
b ^= a;
a ^= b;
```

It works because `x ^ x` equals 0 for any value of x, and thus, `x ^ y ^ x` (in any order) equals y for any values of x and y. It's unlikely to be faster than just using a temporary though (unless you're programming for a CPU with high register contention and no pipelining ability).

Comment: XOR is actually a form of encryption and using it in this way is known as the one-time pad :) ... Since XOR is a reversible operation, your technically encrypting a with b, then setting b to a encrypted with b again, so b is then set to the decrypted a and vice versa with the variable b.

Answer (score 14):

How about using the std libs? ;)

```
std::swap(a,b);
```

Although you may also use the XORing algorithm but dont use it until you really have to.

The reason is well explained [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm):-

> **On modern CPU architectures, the XOR technique is considerably slower
>   than using a temporary variable to do swapping.** One reason is that
>   modern CPUs strive to execute instructions in parallel via instruction
>   pipelines. In the XOR technique, the inputs to each operation depend
>   on the results of the previous operation, so they must be executed in
>   strictly sequential order. If efficiency is of tremendous concern, it
>   is advised to test the speeds of both the XOR technique and temporary
>   variable swapping on the target architecture.

Although its too late but since you have not mentioned that you want build in functions or not hence the `swap` method is the easiest one.

However you may also try to use the XOR method(although check the above reference about its performance) like this:

```
a ^= b;
b ^= a;
a ^= b;
```

Answer (score 4):

Try XORing as below.

```
a ^= b;
b ^= a;
a ^= b;
```